# How do I avoid code dupilcation in my controllers using Codeigniter?

Tags: rest, codeigniter, model-view-controller

this is my first post and my English isn’t that good. So I hope you will understand my question/problem.

I'm using the Codeigniter framework for most of my projects and I always have the same problem. Let's have an example:

1.) A logged in user can change his profile with some basic information’s (e.g. displayname, firstname, lastname). The user submits the form and the controller will handle everything and load another view.

2.) In the administration an administrator wants to change the profile of a user. No problem, he clicks "edit" in his userlist and change the last name and submits the form. I have a second controller for that which does almost the same as the profileController but loads a different view.

That's a lot of code duplication and if I want to add a new attribute (e.g. birthday) I have to update many files.

I think a RESTful approach could be a solution for that problem but I am not very familiar with that. Is there another solution?

Do you get the problem?
Thank you for your patience and help!

Comment: when you go to edit form from admin or user side. show each field data in the input field. And then you can change the desire fields. But you will use all fields at the time of updation

Comment: Well that is generally the idea of models and libraries. Just load the model/library and you should be able to standardize the inputs and how they enter the db. Its really difficult to make any concrete recommendations without code, and even so, that is more of a question for Code Review not Stack Overflow where we deal in concrete (minimal, verifiable) questions  that can be reproduced and solved. I wouldn't say you need REST however.